# C# moving auto generated code to better structure code

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, structure

I am pretty new to C# and wondered if there was a simple way to move the auto-generated code to a separate class file?

For example, if I create a windows form onto which I drag a button. Then if I double click the button it auto generates a click event handler under the main Form1 namespace and class. Is there a way that I can move this code to a separate file (maybe a class.cs file) if I want to structure my code in a neat way rather than having an ever growing main??

All of the quick and dirty 'Hello World' style C# examples just show you how to add items to the form in the way described above... they don't seem to go into best practises on how to structure large code developments where structuring code into separate files can beneficial. Is what am am thinking of necessary or do developers use the standard click handlers (left in the main form) and then use that to call external reference files containing the classes/methods???

I'd be interested if you guys can steer me in the correct direction on the best practices people use to structure large C# form based projects

Many thanks

Michael

Comment: When you create a `Form`, a class with the same name is allotted to handle the events and all the shenanigans related to that form. When you double click a `Button` for example, the events will be created in the same class. Why would you want to move it to a separate class where it does not belong to. But instead if you want to clean up(manage and neatly structure) your main class, have a look at [#regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-region)

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. As I said in my initial question "Is what am am thinking of necessary" - it looks from your answer that I'm barking up the wrong tree. I come from an embedded C background were the norm is to structure your code so the main isn't top heavy for good readability. I'm just trying to get to grips with C#.... there are lots and lots of example for little snippets on how to implement task and functions, but I haven't found a good guide to correct structuring of larger projects yet. Thanks for the tip on regions - that could be useful.

Comment: Any code in the designer.cs file can be moved into any other cs file.  I usually only leave the main controls in the designer file so I can move the location and size on the form.  Any other property settings or events I put into my form constructor or Load() method.  When I create new projects I often copy old code and if the code is in the designer file these setting are lost.

Comment: You can also add a #region so that you can shrink them down and the are effectively hidden while maybe other parts are not

Comment: Hi jdweng, that is also a useful tip..... it's this kind of user knowledge/detail in how people are structuring their C# projects for best practice that I am looking for, rather than the stuff you find regurgitated in every youtube video (i.e. on how to do specific functions or tasks)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can move the event handlers to a "separate" class. You already have two files: Form1.cs and Form1.Designer.cs, each of which contain a partial class. At the top of Form1.cs, you will see:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
```

You can create a new file (called whatever you like) and add in the following:

```
 public partial class Form1
 {

 }
```

You can now move any of your event handlers for Form1 into this new file.

All that said, we've got a suite of 4 Winforms applications totalling about 450 controls, and we've never done this. The most buttons we've had on a form where we use the designer to create the event handler is about 10. Once you have a lot of buttons (such as in a menu), you are much better off not using the designer, and creating the items (and their event handlers) by code.

You will also not end up with one form that contains tens of thousands of lines - instead you will create individual controls which contain isolated logic, and then tie these together on the Form.

Comment: Cool MineR,   From what you are saying it looks like I am doing it fundamentally wrong by using the auto generated event handler by adding a button to the form. I use the form designer so I can see what the form design will look like (WYSIWYG), may I ask how you determine the layout (e.g. positions) to do it programatically ?? P.S. Thaks for all your help guys - its good to hear from professionals in their field

Comment: No, you're not doing it wrong. It's perfectly valid to add event handlers like that manually in many circumstances. But you will also use other methods too. Note when placing a Button on a form, we almost always do this using the designer. But we might subscribe the the event without using the designer. The best method depends on many factors. If you're just starting out, don't worry about all of the issues - just try things out and see what you like the best.

Comment: Hi MineR, Okay thanks for the info. Where would you normally put the event handler code... would it reside in the main form or a separate cs file added to the project to make the code look neater?

Comment: We've always put the event handler in the default location (Form1.cs), when  adding it manually.